# Tensorboard doesn't show runtime/memory for all operations

Tags: tensorflow, runtime, profiling, tensorboard

I have a network implemented in TensorFlow that takes very long to train and therefore want to profile it to see which parts cause the long runtime.

To do that, I follow the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz#runtime_statistics) to capture runtime and memory information. My code looks like this:

```
// define network
loss = ...
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

// run forward and backward prop for one batch
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
_,loss,sum = sess.run([train_op,loss,sum], feed_dict=fd, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step_%d' % step)
```

I can then see "session runs" in TensorBoard. However, as soon as I load a session run, most operations in my graph turn orange as shown below and no runtime or memory information is available for them:

[image]

According to the legend, these operations are "unsused". But that cannot be the case, as almost everything except "loss" and "opt" are shown like that. Clearly, the whole network has to be used to compute the loss. So I don't really see why the graph is shown like this.

I use TF 1.3 on a Tesla K40c.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem as you with Tensorboard not registering anything in my session run except the gradient and optimizer ops.

I fixed it by upgrading my version of Tensorflow to the 1.4 release.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that tomorrow and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.
Try adding this line

```
writer.add_summary(_, step)
```

after

```
writer.add_run_metadata...
```

Comment: Why should I pass _ to the add_summary function? Does that even work?

Comment: _,loss,sum = sess.run([train_op,loss,sum], feed_dict=fd, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

# from this:  _ contains sess.run(train_op,..)